# Arduino IDE giving error for the following code

Tags: arduino, ide, runtime-error, uploading

The code compiles okay but it doesn't upload.
The code is :

```
int fsrPin = 0;     // the FSR and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
int fsrReading;     // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider
 
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);   
}
 
void loop(void) {
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin);  
 
  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.print(fsrReading);     // print the raw analog reading
 
  if (fsrReading < 10) {
    Serial.println(" - No pressure");
  } else if (fsrReading < 200) {
    Serial.println(" - Light touch");
  } else if (fsrReading < 500) {
    Serial.println(" - Light squeeze");
  } else if (fsrReading < 800) {
    Serial.println(" - Medium squeeze");
  } else {
    Serial.println(" - Big squeeze");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

And the error is like this:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x41
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x41
```

I have checked all the ports and code and everything seems fine yet the avr dude error keeps popping up

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there some loose connection with the USB cable and Arduino. Few steps you can follow to counter:

1. Try reconnecting the USB cable.
2. Restart Arduino IDE.
3. Restart PC.

Your problem should be solved.